# Angular2 / Ionic2 : Execute $http.get within Listener

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I am trying **to fetch datas on scroll** and fill an array of "**Article[]**".

```
httpLoadArticles() {
    this.httpWSGetInit().subscribe(
                                   articles => this.articles = articles,
                                    err => {
                                        console.log(err);
                                    },
                    () => console.log('Searching complete')
}
```

And the current function.

```
httpWSGetInit() : Observable<Article []> {

    return this.http.get(R.WEBSITE_URL_WS + this.articlesPagination)
                         .map((res:Response) => res.json())
                         .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
}
```

Works pretty well.

But the `http.get` method is never called in `addScrollListener`.

```
@ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

ionViewDidLoad() {
        this.content.addScrollListener(this.onPageScroll);
}

onPageScroll(event) {
       this.httpLoadArticles()
}
```

I tried to set the `GET` as `synchronous` but it seems to not change anything. Is it a `scope` issue ? Like `addScrollListener` is a pure JS method and cannot be attached to `angular2` container ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes its an scope issue. You should use Arrow function to preserve this context

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.content.addScrollListener(() => this.onPageScroll() );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm :). Do you have any documentation on it ?